# How to show whitespace and tabs but NOT line-break characters?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to switch from Komodo to Eclipse.

I can't figure out how to keep line-break characters from being shown in eclipse - looks like they are shown along with tabs and other whitespace characters.

Is there a way to show tabs and other whitespace characters but not line-break characters?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you have Eclipse 3.7 you can disable them.

Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors -- Look for 'Show whitespace characters' and click on the link 'whitespace characters'.

Comment: Ops, i installed the pdt version, that looks outdated.. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Or you can directly click on the shortcut:[image]

Answer (score 7):

In the Luna version, this configurability is now called "configure visibility" under "Show Withespace characters"

Answer (score 7):

In your Eclipse, go to:

`Window --> Preferences --> General --> Editors --> Text Editors`

Click the highlighted link (configure visibility) in the check-box SHOW WHITESPACE CHARACTERS and select the check box as per your requirement.

[image: Click the highlighted link]