# Remove the display of unknown characters under eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I noticed that my eclipse editor displays unknown characters.
Example: it displays '.' at the link of a space ... But when opening the code with notepad, the java code is clear.

Is there a setting to do under eclipse?

[image]

Comment: "Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors -- uncheck  'Show whitespace characters'" , taken from this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548187/how-to-show-whitespace-and-tabs-but-not-line-break-characters

Comment: Thank you Berger . it works.

Comment: For my case I just uncheck 'Show whitespace characters' and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Preferences menu, then go into:

- General
- Editors
- Text Editors

Then:

1. Search for the checkbox labeled "Show whitespace characters".
2. Uncheck the checkbox in front of it
3. Apply your changes